# How to make a radio button choice limit the range of a number input box

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm sure this is answered somewhere but I can't find it.  I have a radio button and a number field like below.  I want to make it so that when the first radio button is checked, the number box has a max value of 1 and when the other radio button is checked, the max value restriction is removed.

So like this when the first radio is checked

```
<form action="test.html" method="POST">
      <input id="mySelect" type="radio" name="isunique" value="0"> Unique
      <input id="mySelect" type="radio" name="isunique" value="1"> Not Unique
      <input type="number" min="0" max="1" step="1" name="qty">
</form>
```

And like this when the second radio is checked

```
<form action="test.html" method="POST">
      <input id="mySelect" type="radio" name="isunique" value="0"> Unique
      <input id="mySelect" type="radio" name="isunique" value="1"> Not Unique
      <input type="number" min="0" step="1" name="qty">
</form>
```

I tried doing it by using a function call

```
onchange="unlimitqty()"
```

where the function is

```
function unlimitqty() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("qlimit").innerHTML = "<input type=\"number\" min="0\" step=\"1\" name=\"qty\">\n";
}
```

And another function limitqty()

```
function limitqty() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("qlimit").innerHTML = "<input type=\"number\" min=\"0\" max=\"1\" step=\"1\" name=\"qty\">\n";
}
```

Then I put this in the form

```
<p id="qlimit">
```

That produces the right behavior on the page, but the variable does not get passed through when the form gets submitted.

I'm not really looking to fix this approach, I feel there must be a better way.  There must be some javascript built in function that limits number fields.  I just haven't been able to find it.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the maxvalue of your number-input by setting it's attribute.
The first parameter of the setAttribute function takes the value you want to change e.g: 'max', 'min', etc. The second parameter takes the value you want to set to the first parameter. In your case you can change the max value to 1 by doing this:

```
document.getElementById('numberboxID').setAttribute('max', 1);
```

To make the value be infite you can change the parameter 2 to Infinity:

```
document.getElementById('numberboxID').setAttribute('max', Infinity);
```

Edit:
You can set the value to 1 by using:

```
document.getElementById('numberboxID').value = 1;
```

You can also change the max value without using setAttribute:

```
document.getElementById('numberboxID').max = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm working on this now, I may probably have more questions because I know basically nothing about javascript.  I'm well schooled in PHP but I really need to learn javascript soon.

Comment: OMG it works!  And so simple.  One detail though.  When I click on the radio that limits it to a max of 1, how do I make it reset the value of the box to 1 if it's already been set higher?

Comment: I tried adding this:
```
 document.getElementById('qtybox').setAttribute('value', 1);
```
But no luck

Comment: I've updated my answer. It now should work :D

Comment: OMG it works so great, thank you so much!  It had such a simple solution in the end.  I did so much googling before posting here for help, it seems it should have been easier to find.  I wish I could upvote you again, but anyway you made my day.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it:

```js
const inp=document.querySelector("input[type=number");
document.getElementById("max1").onchange=ev=>{
  inp.max=ev.target.checked?(inp.value=Math.min(inp.value,1),"1"):undefined;

}
```

```html
<form action="test.html" method="POST">
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="max1"> max 1</label>
  <input type="number" min="0" step="1" name="qty" style="width:50px">
</form>
```

I took the liberty of replacing your two radio buttons with a single checkbox. This avoids the initial undefined stage (with no radio button selected) and is easier to operate in any case.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm working on this now, will let you all know what worked, if I get it working.   Your time spent is extremely!

Comment: That works nicely as well.  But it has the same problem, that the value does not get reset to 1.  The form will complain if you try to submit it with a value > 1 so it's not the end of the world.  But still would be nicer if the value reset to 1 upon clicking, if it had already been set higher.  Thanks again for your elegant code!

Comment: That is easy to fix :D - see my changed snippet.